# Making Request from Localhost:3000 says NETWORK FAIL to React Native Project

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, react-native, axios

I had watched a series of tutorials online and had followed lot of steps. I had to change my IP address to my machine IP, but yet network error. even, I had to change it to 127.0.0.1. Am just so tired, I need help badly. I am using a project on the PHPMyAdmin database, which I use to fetch the result using express and node MySQL. I did all I could I even used USB tethering, hotspot, and all but none seems to work

```
const GetUserData =()=>{
   axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/users").then(
       (response)=>{
        console.log(response.data);
   }).catch(err =>{
       console.log(err);
   })
}; 

useEffect(() => {
  GetUserData()
},[])
```

Comment: Can you add the error message, please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the error message, please?  If you face CORS you can fix it by:

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Please, How can I add the following can you explain in details, where am I adding it Please...

Comment: you can follow this tutorial https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 0):

Your machine has multiple IP addresses, even with one network device.

Of them:

- `127.0.0.1` - local IP address. It is not on any network device, and it should not be there.
- `192.168.x.y` - network IP address. It is configured on the network device (manually or automatically).

You don't need to install `127.0.0.1` on a network device. `127.0.0.1` is already your machine, even without any network devices.

Also, to be able to make requests to `127.0.0.1:3000`, some service must already listen on this port.

Comment: So, please what do you suggest that I should do...?

Comment: @VictorOkon, start the server at `127.0.0.1:3000` (or `0.0.0.0:3000`) and make requests to `127.0.0.1:3000` without changing any network settings.